# The monitor don't work with digital signal processing

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, signal-processing

I make a ‘photoplethysmograph’ with Raspberry pi(CM3+) and Maxim sensor(max30102).

I connect between Raspberry pi and Maxim sensor by I2C. I write python program. I want to display ‘photoplethysmograpy’ in canvas.

First, I am success to display that, but noise appear.(program0)

Second, I try to use digital signal processing for removing noise.

```
sampling frequency: 100Hz
band pass filter  :0.1Hz : 10Hz
```

I write program with band pass filter(progmam1) But, the following error message appear and the program don't move. I want to improve program1. What should I do?

error message:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/signal/signaltools.py:1344: FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
  out = out_full[ind]
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/exercize/r210210.py", line 62, in sensor
    self.add_point0(self.l0,y0_digital/2000)
  File "/home/pi/exercize/r210210.py", line 80, in add_point0
    self.c0.coords(line, *coords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2469, in coords
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'coords') + args))]
_tkinter.TclError: bad screen distance "[1.50422694e-04 1.51988575e-02 1.51988575e-02 2.08"
```

program:

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import time
import max30102
import scipy.signal as signal


class Test():
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("800x600")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.flag = True
    
    self.c0 = tk.Canvas(self.frame, bg="white", widt=760, height=160)
    self.c0.grid(row=0,column=0)
    self.c1 = tk.Canvas(self.frame, bg="white", widt=760, height=160)
    self.c1.grid(row=1,column=0)
    self.buttonB = tk.Button(self.frame, text="start",command=self.measure)
    self.buttonB.grid(row=2,column=0)
    
    self.l0 = self.c0.create_line(0,80,0,80,fill="blue")
    self.l1 = self.c1.create_line(0,80,0,80,fill="blue")
    self.l2 = self.c0.create_line(0,80,0,80,fill="red")
    
    self.frame.grid()
    
    

def measure(self):
    th0 = threading.Thread(target=self.sensor)
    
    if self.buttonB['text'] == "start":
        self.buttonB['text'] = "stop"
        self.flag = True
        th0.start()
    else:
        self.buttonB['text'] = "start"
        self.flag = False


def sensor(self):
    m = max30102.MAX30102()
    
    a,b = signal.buttord([0.002,0.2],[0.001,0.3],3,40)
    y0 = []
    y1 = []
    
    while self.flag:
        red, ir = m.read_fifo()
        print('RED'+str(red))
        print('IR'+str(ir))
        #self.add_point0(self.l0, (red/2000))
        #self.add_point1(self.l1, (ir/2000))
        
        y0.append(red)
        y1.append(ir)
        
        if len(y0) >= 100:
            y0_digital = signal.lfilter(b,a,y0)
            y1_digital = signal.lfilter(b,a,y1)
            self.add_point0(self.l0,y0_digital/2000)
            self.add_point1(self.l1.y1_digital/2000)
            
            self.c0.xview_moveto(1.0)
            self.c1.xview_moveto(1.0)
            y0.pop(0)
            y1.pop(0)
            
        time.sleep(0.01)
        
    m.shutdown()
    
def add_point0(self, line, y):
    coords = self.c0.coords(line)
    x = coords[-2] + 1
    coords.append(x)
    coords.append(y)
    coords = coords[-1500:]
    self.c0.coords(line, *coords)
    self.c0.configure(scrollregion=self.c0.bbox("all"))
    
def add_point1(self, line, y):
    
    coords = self.c1.coords(line)
    x = coords[-2] + 1
    coords.append(x)
    coords.append(y)
    coords = coords[-1600:]
    self.c1.coords(line, *coords)
    self.c1.configure(scrollregion=self.c1.bbox("all"))
    

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Test(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: IMHO, I think you would do well to extract all the image acquisition and processing from your Tkinter display stuff and put that into a separate module or at least separate functions. Then you can write a test harness for all the image processing stuff and just create a PNG without all the Tkinter stuff. Otherwise you will only get answers, and future maintenance support, from the dwindling pool of engineers who know I2C **AND** image processing **AND** Tkinter **AND** RasPi.

Comment: Tkank you, Mr.Mark Setchell. I try to rewrite the source code after my other job.